# CRM Dynamics - How to re-upload a customised ".rdl" file belonging to an existing report

Tags: dynamics-crm

I've been asked to make cosmetic changes to a report created by a third-party consultant on our CRM Dynamics 2011 system. The report apparently has a "report type" of "Existing File" when viewed in the "Edit" window, but has a "report type" of "Reporting Services Report" when viewed in the list of reports. If anyone can provide some clarity on this, it may be of some help.

[image: The existing report is shown as a Reporting Services Report]

Anyway I've been able to download the ".rdl" file behind the report and make the necessary changes (removed a paragraph in the footer). When I re-upload my new ".rdl" file and click the "Save" button, I receive the error of "**You can not change the report type for an existing report**". However I'm only attempting to change the report template rather than the report type.

[image: The error when reuploading the .rdl file]

My second strategy was to create a new report in the same way that I assume the original report was created. When creating a new report, the first option I am given is to select the "Report Type".

If I go down the path of selecting "Report Wizard Report" for the report type, then I don't get the option to select an ".rdl" file.

If I go down the path of selecting "Existing File" for the report type, then when I try and run my report it unhelpfully downloads the ".rdl" file for me! It also regards the new report as having a "report type" of "Other Report" when viewed in the list of reports.

[image: My attempt at recreating the original report]

Can anyone put me out of my misery?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with re-uploading the amended report was with the file extension of the upload.

For some reason when downloading the report file, CRM Dynamics decided to put single quotes around the file names. So instead of:

```
ReportName.rdl
```

I received:

```
'ReportName.rdl'
```

Once I removed the quotes from the file name, I was able to re-upload successfully.

Comment: It’s not CRM added the quote, but the Chrome browser.